# Is it possible to dynamically change Integrated Runtime in Linked service in ADF?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data factory as data ingestion service.We have over 100 SHIR at different locations and need to ingest data from all the locations to one centralized DW. So, we need to change SHIR dynamically when we connect with different data sources. The ADF offers parameterized linked service. So, we will be able to change the linked service parameters such as DB name, connection string etc.But,Is it possible to change SHIR dynamically in ADF linked service?

Thank you in advance.

My expectation is dynamically changing SHIR in ADF

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to parameterize Integration runtime in a linked service currently.

Answer (score 0):

You can create parameterized Linked Services but those work only where there is dynamic content supported :
[image]

unfortunately the IR is a picklist and cannot be added manually , so you cannot parameterize it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Data Factory, you can't easily switch SHIR dynamically within a linked service. The simpler approach is to create separate linked services for each SHIR and pick the right one when needed. You can use tools like Azure Logic Apps to help with this.